# How to generate samples from a random number generator in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a random number generator function. I want to use this function to generate 100 samples for simulation and make a histogram of it. Can anybody tell me how I can do in Matlab?

This random number generator is from a distribution.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html

Comment: Please, don't insult the people here by asking them to do your work. First try to solve it on your own, then, if you get stuck, come back here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is just to call it in a loop:

```
x = zeros(1,100);
for i = 1:100
    x(i) = my_func();
end
```

And then:

```
hist(x)
```